# How to set persistence provider for Empire

Tags: jpa, orm, persistence, rdf, semantic-web

I am working on the data access layer for rdf. For mapping of java objects to rdf i have used "Empire" tool (by Clark & Parsia).

It is giving error on following line

EntityManager aManager=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("oreilly").createEntityManager();

Error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named oreilly
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:56)
  at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
  at Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

I have set the 0.name=oreilly in properties file and also checked the path of properties file but still its giving the error.

```
System.setProperty("empire.configuration.file", "examples.empire.config.properties");
EntityManager aManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("oreilly").createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a JPA implementation such as eclipselink.jar on your classpath.

Comment: I have added all required jars in the project.